# data structure for storing huge(>5GB) sorted file

Tags: python, algorithm

Suppose we have a csv file(>5GB) which contains Employee name and Age column. The file is sorted by Age.
Now,I want users to search this file using Age. Can someone please guide me which of the data structures is best suited for this requirement ?

**Example**:

myfile.csv

```
25 ABC    
25 MNP
14 XYZ
14 PQR
```

**input**:

```
14
```

**output**:

```
XYZ
PQR
```

Comment: I would feed it into a database and search that, or at least sort it by age.

Comment: @waleed Khan: Yes, file is sorted using Age.

Comment: Why not break it into separate files?

Comment: Being pedantic, that's not a CSV file :)

Comment: @SRC If the file is already sorted by age, you can use random access and binary search.

Comment: @WaleedKhan: Files on disk do not have random access, assuming the file is indeed huge - it is a problem. Note that binary search will still be `O(logn)` here, but the constants will be terrible.

Comment: @Joel Cornett: yes, you got it. Its not csv but please imagine it :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the file is too big to fit in RAM, you can create an index, and this way you can minimize the number of disk reads (which are much slower then RAM reads).

Some often used indexes for disks are [B+ trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B+_tree) (where the top levels are stored in RAM) and [hash tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table).

Alternatively, you can store it as an [SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL) table and let the library take care for itself.

Another alternative, since the range is fairly small (I cannot imagine an age being greater then 200), you can use 200 (or probably less) different files: `names_1,names_2,...,names_200` where `names_i` holds a list of all the names whom age are `i`.

(Also, since the age is ommitted in many entriesthis way, you might be able to actually fit it in RAM as a `dictionary:age->list<names>`)

If the data fits RAM - you can use a sorted array (if changes in the data are not often/not expected) and use a binary search. 

If you need to make changes in the data, you can use some other structures such as a hash table on RAM, or a [self balancing BST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree)

Comment: When the answer involves B-trees, use a database :)

Comment: @AlexandreC.: Unless it is an interview/HW, and you should actually know how to implement it. Anyhow, I do advise using SQL (or some other database system) to store the data if it is for a real life project.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't indicated if your infrastructure allows for an in-memory solution. If it does, seeing that you have tagged your question with python, I would look at reading the contents of the file into a defaultdict. If the performance is acceptable, you have a quick standard library-based solution

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> z = defaultdict(list)
>>> z[25].append("ABC")
>>> z[25].append("MNP")
>>> print z[25]
['ABC', 'MNP']
```